# Smart Table st-search inside nested objects

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

Is there any way to search inside nested elements in smart-table? I feed the table with data from a REST Api that consists of the following form:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "small_name": "Foo",
    "large_name": "Bar Foo",
    "variants": [{"value": "0"}, {"value": "1"}]
}
```

What I want to achieve is the possibility to filter the data through the `value` property of the objects inside the `variants`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Smart Table documentation:

"The stSetFilter replaces the filter used when searching through Smart Table. When the default behavior for stSearch does not meet your demands, like in a select where one entry is a substring of another, use a custom filter to achieve your goals."
http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/

There is also an example available at that site.

Comment: Thanks. I should have paid more attention to the `smart-table` site, thanks to that I was able to do that filter.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post the solution for my problem, maybe it can help someone.

```
angular.module('YourModule').filter('CustomFilter', [
    '$parse',
    function ($parse) {
        return function(items, filters) {
            console.log(items, filters);

            var itemsLeft = items.slice();

            Object.keys(filters).forEach(function (model) {
                var value = filters[model],
                    getter = $parse(model);

                itemsLeft = itemsLeft.filter(function (item) {
                    if (model === 'value') {
                        var variants = item.variants.filter(function (variant) {
                           return getter(variant).match(value);
                        });

                        return variants.length;
                    } else {
                        return getter(item).match(value);
                    }
                });
            });

            return itemsLeft;
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Can you update your answer, include html and also make a plunker/fiddle so that others can more understand your Answer.